# I put YouTube embedded code in my website but I can't disable share button help me in this problem

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I remove the watch later and share buttons from youtube iframe embed player. Using the following embed code for embedding video clips.

i use this parameter but still not working

**"showinfo=0"** and **"controls=0"**

Comment: using the `controls` only for `<video>` element , so you can't edit the embed (`<iframe>`) with `controls` or `showinfo` ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `no cookie` version of the video, to disable the "watch later" and "share" buttons.

If your embed code looks like this:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

You have to change it to this:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

or just check the checkbox in the youtube embed window.

This way, your URL will just look a little bit different:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g`

is changed to

`https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g`

and the "watch later" and "share" buttons will be hidden automatically.

Comment: Thank you it is worked but this show me copy link button this is the second problem..i don't want to copied link user only can view my youtube video.

Comment: Would be great if you accept the answer as it solved your issue. The question is about the other two buttons. Feel free to open a new question with a view more infos (don't get the "want to copied link user only can view"...? ) and comment here the link to the new question, so I get notified to answer you.